# What's the difference between `:e foo.ext` and `:n foo.ext`

Tags: vimscript

As title. Sorry for being possibly a very simple question but could anyone rephrase the answer so it can be easily understood by a beginner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using two different commands, `:e` and `:n`, that are thoroughly documented.

`:help :edit_f` says:

```
:e[dit] [++opt] [+cmd] {file}
                        Edit {file}.
                        This fails when changes have been made to the current
                        buffer, unless 'hidden' is set or 'autowriteall' is
                        set and the file can be written.
                        Also see |++opt| and |+cmd|.
```

while `:help :next_f` says:

```
Same as |:args_f|.
```

and `:help :args_f` says:

```
:ar[gs] [++opt] [+cmd] {arglist}            *:args_f*
                        Define {arglist} as the new argument list and edit
                        the first one.  This fails when changes have been made
                        and Vim does not want to |abandon| the current buffer.
                        Also see |++opt| and |+cmd|.
```

So…

- `:e filename` edits `filename`,
- `:n filename` sets the argument list to `filename` and edit `filename`.

If, *in fine*, both commands give you a `filename` buffer to edit, they have different side-effects. If you are confident those side-effects are irrelevant to you, then you can use them interchangeably. If not, use the command that does exactly what you want.

FWIW, the basics are introduced in chapter 7 of the user manual: `:help usr_07`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I didn't know that `:` can still be appended after `:h`, now I learned it.

Answer (score 1):

In this case (just a single filename folliwing `:e` and `:n`) they're basically identical.

You can see the definitive builtin help `:h edit_f` and `:h next_f` (just few lines below `:h :e` and `:h :n`). Use `Ctrl-]` to jump between helps, and `Ctrl-O` to jump back.